# Can I revert app submission before approvement

Tags: macos, react-native, app-store

I asked how can I deploy an .IPA file to testflight. I was told, that I need to open 'Application Loader', put there my file and submit it. So, I did it, but after submitting, it told me that now I have to wait until application is approved to App Store. I guess, I did something wrong, so is there a way to revert this submission?

Comment: it takes a day or 2 for iOS to review your app. You have to go through this process each time you submit an app or an update to the App Store.

Comment: Log in to https://itunesconnect.apple.com/login and you should be able to get a clearer view of how the processing is going.